# XPages - disable client side validation for Dojo Time Text Box

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus

I want to disable client side validation for a Dojo Time Text Box control while making this a required field for server side validation. I have set both the "disableClientSideValidation" and "validatorExt" properties to true. However, when I open the XPage, I immediately see the error "This value is required" beside the Dojo Time Text Box. Here is my code:

```
<xe:djTimeTextBox id="EventStartTime" value="#document1.EventStartTime}"     required="true"               
disableClientSideValidation="true" 
promptMessage="Bitte fügen Sie diesem Feld einen Wert hinzu!"
validatorExt="true">
<xe:this.validators>
<xp:validateRequired>
<xp:this.message><![CDATA[Bitte füllen Sie das Feld "Event Start Zeit" aus!]]>                 
</xp:this.message>
</xp:validateRequired>
</xe:this.validators>
</xe:djTimeTextBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `xe:djTimeTextBox` with the Attribute `required="true"` it will create a html Output like this:

```
<input name="view:_id1:EventStartTime" id="view:_id1:EventStartTime" required="true" promptmessage="Bitte fügen Sie diesem Feld einen Wert hinzu!" dojotype="dijit.form.TimeTextBox">
```

You can view this code when using the noscript plugin for Firefox and set it to disable all scripts. This is the Output befor dojo is transforming your Input in a dojo Text Box.

The Problem is that if you use this extlib prebuild field the `required` attribute will get written to the input as soon you set this field to `required=true` no mather if you disable client side validation or not. The workaround for this could be to use a standard input and add the dojo attributes then you can set required on Server Side only like this:

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dijit.form.TimeTextBox"></xp:dojoModule>
</xp:this.resources>

<xp:inputText id="mtgTime1" style="width:160px;" role="button"
    title="used to pick a meeting time" required="true"
    dojoType="dijit.form.TimeTextBox" disableClientSideValidation="true">
    <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="required" value="false"></xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateRequired>
            <xp:this.message><![CDATA[Bitte füllen Sie das Feld "Event Start Zeit" aus!]]></xp:this.message>
        </xp:validateRequired>
    </xp:this.validators>
</xp:inputText>
<xp:messages id="messages1"></xp:messages>
<xp:button id="test" value="tst">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this great solution. This has solved my issue.